# mysql mariadb - not able to access mysql db once the container is started until restarts the container

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

Using sql client or terminal, not able to access mysql database once the mariadb container is created. we can access the db inside the container but not from outside. From outside we can access the db only after restart the container. Below is my config, kindly help!

```
services:
  db:
     image: mariadb:10.4.10
     restart: always
     environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd@123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: my_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd@123
      command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    ports:
      - "33067:3306"
    volumes:
      - ../mariadb/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
   networks:
     my_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.27.1.7
```

Not able to access from host and from another container, while trying to access from host, getting below error,

```
yah@yahv:~/yah/docker/myDock$ mysql -umy_user -ppwd@shroot -h172.27.1.7 -P3306
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.27.1.7' (111)
```

After some hours, not sure exactly how much time, i am able to access the db. I am sure this happens without restarting the container but not sure whether the sql process inside the db got restarted or not!

Comment: check your error logs of the mariadb, i think it doesn't like    volumes:
      - ../mariadb/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql becuase that should be a folder as destination

Comment: How are you trying to access it?  From where (another container, outside Docker on the same host, another host)?  What specific error do you get?

Comment: @DavidMaze getting error from both host and other containers, updated the question with error details

Comment: @nbk - i dont think anything to do with volume here, something related to permission in config file, that is why it works once the container restarted

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
ports:
  - "33067:3306"
```

your connection line must be

```
mysql -umy_user -ppwd@shroot -h172.27.1.7 -P33067
```

Comment: since i expose 33067 i have to use it with locahost -->

Comment: no issue with port,  this is something else with permission,
both of the below will work,
 mysql -umy_user -ppwd@shroot -h172.28.0.7 -P3306 OR \n
 mysql -umy_user -ppwd@shroot -h127.0.01 -P33067

Comment: So does it work or not, localhost wiill try zty to use sockets or named pipes depending on your operating system. Try to connect via mysql command to exclude that your user can access the database